# Understanding what $I \cdot J$ means when $I$ and $J$ are ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have the following definition

> For ideals $I, J$ of a ring $R$, their product $I J$ is defined as the ideal of $R$ generated by the elements of the form $x y$ where $x \in I$ and $y \in J$.

Does this mean that
$$
IJ = \langle S \rangle
$$
where $S = \{xy : x \in I, y \in J \}$?

If this is the case then am struggling with something that according to other questions on this website is obvious. People seem to assert that $IJ \subset I \cap J$ but to me this is not obvious. According to my definitions:

> Defn (Generator of ideal) For $A \subseteq R$ a subset, the ideal generated by $A$ is
> $$
> (A)=\left\{\sum_{a \in A} r_a \cdot a: r_a \in R, \text{ only finitely-many non-zero }\right\}.
> $$

I do not see how the containment is trivially true then. Are my definitions wrong or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Good question! In algebra, often there's a notion of "subobject generated by a set $S$". (EG: subgroup, vector subspace, submodule, subring, ideal). An important fact is that the subobject generated by $S$ is the smallest subobject containing $S$, meaning if $X$ is a subobject containing $S$, then $X$ contains the subobject generated by $S$. (Probably you've seen this in a groups course!) I think this point of view is probably why $IJ \subseteq I \cap J$ is considered to be trivial - because you can "automatically" reframe it as $S \subseteq I \cap J$, which is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are entirely right about $IJ$. It is equal to $\langle S\rangle$, just as you described.

As for the containment, can you see that every single element of $S$ is contained in $I$? Can you see that every single element of $S$ is contained in $J$? Thus by definition of intersection, $S\subseteq I\cap J$. Can you see why this implies $\langle S\rangle\subseteq I\cap J$?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick response. I see why every element of $S$ is contained in $J$ and in $I$, that is, it comes of the definition of the ideals $I$ and $J$. For the last point, is it because in the sum first multiplying by $r_a$ doesn't change the fact that will be in both ideals, and then, summing will still keep us in both ideals as we know that the ideals are additive subgroups meaning we have closure?

Comment: @MathsWizzard That's as good a reason as any.

Answer (score 2):

More formally you have

- $I\cdot J\subset I\cdot A\subset I$, and
- $I\cdot J\subset A\cdot J\subset J$.

Putting the two things together you have $I\cdot J\subset I\cap J$.